# Better way to resolve a list of path strings to a different path in make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using an autogenerated make file from Atmel.  When linking, it uses a variable, $(OBJS_AS_ARGS).  where:

```
OBJS_AS_ARGS +=  \
"hal/src/hal_io.o" \
"hpl/systick/hpl_systick.o" \
"samd21a/gcc/gcc/startup_samd21.o" \
"hal/utils/src/utils_syscalls.o" \
"hal/src/hal_delay.o" \
"hpl/pm/hpl_pm.o" \
"hpl/core/hpl_init.o" \
"samd21a/gcc/system_samd21.o" \
"hpl/core/hpl_core_m0plus_base.o" \
```

my goal is to alter each string's path to be relative to the parent, i.e.:

```
OBJS_AS_ARGS +=  \  
"../hal/src/hal_io.o" \
"../hpl/systick/hpl_systick.o" \
```

I prepend ../ I was thinking of some vpath way of doing this.  Or perhaps string concatenation.  However, the variable is a list of strings.  I ended up adding ../ to each string.  Is there a way to set up a variable/vpath that would work instead of me modifying each string?  THank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do exactly, but by going with your examples does this do what you want?  More information on the [patsubst function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html).

```
NEW_ARGS := $(patsubst "%","../%",$(OBJS_AS_ARGS))
```

Comment: WOW!  Yes.  Thank you.  I truly appreciate you taking time to teach me something new.  Again, thank you.